Relative risk estimation in spatstat or sparr package and Modeling Bivariate Spatial point process
I'm new to the field of point process research and I'm working with data on forest species (4 different species). I conducted first and second-order analysis for each species, tested the dependency structure for individuals of the same species using Linhom and Jinhom functions for species that showed spatial intensity variability, and L and J for those that didn't show spatial intensity variability. I also modeled the distribution of individuals of the same species for each type of forest species according to the observed dependency structure (Cox: Matérn, Cauchy, LGCP, Gamma Variance, and Thomas (Clustering); Gibbs: Strauss (Inhibition)). Now, I would like to study the relationship between different species pairwise, and the questions are:

In addition to first and second-order intensity and dependency structure using distance functions or K or Kinhom and their extensions, would it be correct to calculate the relative risk (relrisk) considering the occurrence of one species in relation to another to assess which species has more dominance over the other in the study area, looking at the case of pairwise species?

How to model these species considering the bivariate case when I find possible clustering, since Spatstat doesn't have the implementation of Bivariate Cox models so far?

The species have been studied from 1987 to the last forest inventory in 2017, and in the case of 2017, I found that some plants died for all species. Would it make sense to study the relative risk of death of these forest species to see pairwise which is more prone to die?


I appreciate everyone's help, as I mentioned, I'm new to this field but I'm writing my dissertation in this area as a way to learn more and understand.

This is a lot of questions.
The stackoverflow community can advise you how to use software, but you are basically asking for research advice; a research adviser would be the best person to ask.
It would be best to read the textbooks to learn the fundamentals.
In answer to your question 1, intensity, density and relrisk are first order methods which investigate the average number of points. relrisk can be used to study whether points of different types (eg trees of different species) are segregated from each other. The related function segregation.test provides a formal statistical test. The function ppm allows you to fit models. On the other hand, dependence between points (whether they are points of the same type or of different types) involves higher order statistics such as pairwise counts (Kest, pcf, Kcross, pcfcross etc) or nearest neighbour statistics (Gest, Gcross etc). There is a very wide range of tools available, summarised in the spatstat book.
For questions 2 and 3 you are asking for capabilities that are not yet implemented in spatstat.
